# what causes permission of auto-mount in linaro linux

Tags: linux, sd-card, linaro, automount

Sdcard is mounted automatically as root permission. 
like this.

```
/dev/mmcblk1p1 on /media/linaro/11bf7464-471c-42ca-bbc8-d229a43e8fe51 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
```

/etc/fstab is emtpy like below.

```
linaro@linaro-alip:/lib/udev$ cat /etc/fstab 
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
```

did udisks mount the device? If so, where can I change mount permission option?

Sometimes, it is mounted as a linaro user.
What causes this difference? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For Gnone to disable `Nautilus` automount use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```